# Oracle Error sql ORA-00917: missing comma

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Oracle SQL and I have two tables. One named Cars which is a relational table and a second named Or_cars which is an object-relational table. I am trying to insert into Or_cars table the data from Cars table but I am getting this error.

```
CREATE TABLE Cars(
carid NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
carDATE DATE,
model VARCHAR(30),
netamount NUMBER,
tax NUMBER,
totalamount NUMBER
);

CREATE TYPE AmountType AS OBJECT(
netamount NUMBER,
tax NUMBER,
totalamount NUMBER
);

CREATE TABLE Or_cars(
carid NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
carDATE DATE,
model VARCHAR(30),
amount AmountType
);

INSERT INTO Or_cars (carid, carDATE, model, amount(netamount, tax, totalamount))
    SELECT carid, carDATE, model, netamount, tax, totalamount
    FROM Cars;
```

Comment: Ok i added the create table statement for both tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `INSERT INTO` part you have to list *column names* not values. So for the `or_cars` table this needs to be:

```
INSERT INTO Or_cars (carid, cardate, model, amount)
```

As `amount` is of type `amounttype` you need to provide an instance of that type in the `select` statement, not as part of the column list. To create a new instance of an object type, you need to use the name of the type to create it, e.g. `AmountType(1,2,3)`

So the final insert statement should be:

```
INSERT INTO or_cars (carid, cardate, model, amount)
SELECT carid, carDATE, model, AmountType(netamount, tax, totalamount)
FROM Cars;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO Or_cars (carid, carDATE, model, AmountType(netamount, tax, totalamount))
    SELECT carid, carDATE, model, netamount, tax, totalamount
    FROM Cars;
```

You should use the **AmountType** not **amount** for the custom type.

Comment: `AmountType(netamount, tax, totalamount)` is not a column name